# How can I make a curved world in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js, shader, three20

I am creating a project in Three.js in which I have a character **walking on a curved world** (like Animal Crossing).

I finished the part of the character's movements but I can't figure out how to create this 'curved world'.

I would like the result looks **like this**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kY4v-L3rvY (**0:47 - 0:56**).

I thought about **creating a simple plan and applying a shader to make it curved** but I haven't found anything around that can help me.
In Unity there are many shaders that do this but I couldn't find anything in Three.js.

How could I create a shader that allows me to achieve this goal?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [`How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your question is very broad and conceptual. I suggest researching this further on your own (start with vertex shaders), and ask a more focused question when you have hit a block in your understanding/implementation.